# Unable to drag and drop text from DataGridView to TextBox C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, drag-and-drop

I have been using code that others online have supplied but for some reason it won't let me drag items from the datagridview to the textbox. I highlight a row in the dataGridView and try to drag it to the textbox but nothing happens. I have also enabled the drop property for the textBox but still no difference. Here's the code that I am using:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
         {
             DataGridView.HitTestInfo info = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
             if (info.RowIndex >= 0)
             {
                 if (info.RowIndex >= 0 && info.ColumnIndex >= 0)
                 {
                     string text = (String)
                      dataGridView1.Rows[info.RowIndex].Cells[info.ColumnIndex].Value;
                     if (text != null)
                         dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                 }
             }
         }
    }

    private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {
            textBox1.Text = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
```

Comment: is this on a desktop app or web app?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small sample that i have done to give you an idea on how to do this... works perfectly for me. I used WinForms here. If WPF, there may be some more events you will need to register to in order for the drag+drop to register...

Note that you will want to add more code here and there to perform what you really want to do when you drag an item from one control to the other.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Rectangle dragBoxFromMouseDown;
    private int rowIndexFromMouseDown;
    private int rowIndexOfItemUnderMouseToDrop;
    private DataGridViewRow draggedrow;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<StringValue> Items = new List<StringValue>() { new StringValue("1"), new StringValue("2"), new StringValue("3"), new StringValue("4"), new StringValue("5"), new StringValue("6") };
        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = Items;

    }



    private void dataGridView1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Button & MouseButtons.Left) == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            // If the mouse moves outside the rectangle, start the drag.
            if (dragBoxFromMouseDown != Rectangle.Empty &&
                !dragBoxFromMouseDown.Contains(e.X, e.Y))
            {

                // Proceed with the drag and drop, passing in the list item.                    
                DragDropEffects dropEffect = dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(
                dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndexFromMouseDown],
                DragDropEffects.Move);
            }
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Get the index of the item the mouse is below.
        rowIndexFromMouseDown = dataGridView1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y).RowIndex;
        if (rowIndexFromMouseDown != -1)
        {
            // Remember the point where the mouse down occurred. 
            // The DragSize indicates the size that the mouse can move 
            // before a drag event should be started.                
            Size dragSize = SystemInformation.DragSize;

            // Create a rectangle using the DragSize, with the mouse position being
            // at the center of the rectangle.
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = new Rectangle(new Point(e.X - (dragSize.Width / 2),
                                                           e.Y - (dragSize.Height / 2)),
                                dragSize);
            this.draggedrow = this.dataGridView1.CurrentRow;
        }
        else
            // Reset the rectangle if the mouse is not over an item in the ListBox.
            dragBoxFromMouseDown = Rectangle.Empty;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
    }

    private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        this.textBox1.Text = (string)this.draggedrow.Cells["Value"].Value;
    }


}

public class StringValue
{
    public StringValue(string s)
    {
        _value = s;
    }
    public string Value { get { return _value; } set { _value = value; } }
    string _value;
}
```

Comment: I've just tried that code and still the same as before :/ do I need to change the properties of the datagridview or textbox at all? I have already enabled the drop option under properties for the text box

Comment: I have mine both set to AllowDrop. nothing more. Did you subscribe to all of the events properly as well? Just pasting my code in will not tie your object` events to the proper code...

Comment: yes I adapted your code to be compatible with the form components I have. I also set both the textbox and datagridview properties to AllowDrop and still doesn't make any difference :(

Comment: that is very strange. It works great for me. Is this a WinForms or WPF project?

Comment: Here's exactly what i did...
1: create new winforms project
2: double-click on form1 in UI
3: copy-paste my code by replacing current up to last }
4: place DataGridView on form1
5: place TextBox on form1
6: select GridView and subscribe to events you copy-pasted
7: select TextBox and subscribe to events you copy-pasted
8: set GridView and TextBox to AllowDrop = true
9: Run
10: Select and Drag and entire ROW from the gridview onto the textbox...
Done.

Comment: yes that's exactly what I did. I even made a new project and pasted all of your code in there. This is very annoying as it looks like it should work :(

Comment: it should and does on my machine... i am selecting and dragging the entire row however, not just a cell... otherwise it does not work. And it's not perfect either... for example, i have to click on a row FIRST (for it to save into the global var) and then re-click and drag it for the text to show up in the textbox...

Comment: you have only populated the dataGridView with one column though haven't you? I've been trying to drag the single cell as well as click the side bar to highlight the whole row (still highlighting only 1 cell though) and it still doesn't work

Comment: yup just the one column... and i don't drag the cells... just the entire row. Hence the comment of : "you will have to add more code to do what you want it to do..." -- i don't know what to say as it works for me on multiple OS versions and multiple .Net Frameworks and VS instances....

Answer (score 0):

can't you use **DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e** instead of hittest for getting row index in dataGridView1_CellMouseDown. below is your code modified hope this helps

```
  private void dataGridView1_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {


            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && e.ColumnIndex >= 0)
                {
                    string text = (String)
                     dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Value;
                    if (text != null)
                        dataGridView1.DoDragDrop(text, DragDropEffects.Copy);
                }
            }  

        }
    }

    private void textBox1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(typeof(System.String)))
        {
            textBox1.Text = (System.String)e.Data.GetData(typeof(System.String));
        }
    }

    private void textBox1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for your comment Ginish but your code didn't work for me either :(

Comment: have you Ginish got any idea why your code and MaxOvrdrv's code doesn't work for me? it is very odd

Comment: strange enough . this code is working perfectly here. i am using .net 4.5 . what's yours

Comment: yeah me too. 4.5.1. hmmm :S

Comment: instead of highlight the entire row and drag, using above code did you check just by clicking any cell and drag to textbox.

Comment: Yes I did and made no difference unfortunately. So are you using a standard text box? not a rich text box? Do you know of a similar way of achieving the same thing? I have no idea why it isn't working for me

Comment: i am using standard textbox not richtextbox. this is a pretty simple solution. my only doubt is about the datatype of value in cell .

Comment: would you be willing to send your project over so that I can run it on my PC and see if it works? I'm not sure if that is possible or even allowed though?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure myself! :/

Comment: hey guys. I'm still unable to get the drag and drop working :/ was wondering if you had any more ideas on why it isn't working and also what alternative component can I use instead of the dataGridView to display data and be able to drag and drop?